# Music 21 finds notes with duration 1/3 when there are none

Tags: python, music21

I wrote a python script to extract all the notes, their offset, and durations from a midi file. I have achieved this, but I have a problem with the quarterlengths (the duration in quarter notes). I get many notes with duration 1/3, or some other multiple of a third. However, as far as I can tell, none of the notes have any duration of 1/3, because they are all quarter notes, half notes, or sixteenth notes. Where are these durations coming from?

I've tried using pieces with different times signatures, but both 4/4 pieces, 3/4 pieces, and 3/2 pieces come up with 1/3 quarter lengths for some of the notes. Here is my code for reference:

```
lis = []
s = converter.parse("music2/" + "bwv525-1.mid")
a = s.flat
for item in a.notes:
    print(item.duration.type, item.duration.dots, item.quarterLength)
```

where bwv525-1.mid is the file I am reading

Comment: Can you give us a sample output?

Comment: Here's part of the output: eighth 0 0.5
eighth 0 1/3
eighth 0 1/3
16th 0 0.25
quarter 0 1.0
eighth 0 1/3
eighth 0 1/3
eighth 0 1/3
eighth 0 1/3
16th 0 0.25
16th 0 0.25
16th 0 0.25
16th 0 0.25
16th 0 0.25

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleDuration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this piece well and this encoding: most of its notes are encoded as 1/3 length eighth notes and 1/6 length sixteenth rests to give them some separation.

MIDI files generally encode performance not scores.

Comment: is there a way to know which notes are being shortened and which ones are normal length? Essentially, is there a way to correctly represent them?

Comment: Not w/ MIDI -- it's the reason why MusicXML and other formats were invented.